# Did I just increase the db hit count (x2) by adding a node label into my cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cql, neo4j-apoc

So I'm working with your typical "products with tags" data model, where `Product` nodes have an `id` property and `Tag` nodes have `name` property. To my surprise, my query has far more db hits when I include a `Product` label.

I was profiling my queries on matches between products and lists of tags of various lengths.

According to Mark Needham and Petra Selmer (great [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3CvwVTCgK0Y) in Graph Connect Europe 2016), adding the label `Product` in the query would drastically improve performance since we restrict the search space of the query. Makes total sense. Curiously enough, at the beginning I had ~~accidentally~~ omitted the `Product` label. When I added into the query, the db hit count almost doubled, going from 5803 to 10316!

Here is the query I was using:

```
PROFILE MATCH (product:Product)-[:TAGGED]->(tag:Tag)
WHERE tag.name IN ["tag_1","tag_2",..."tag_N"]
WITH product, COLLECT (tag.name) AS tags_list
RETURN product.id, tags_list;
```

Since I can't believe my eyes right now, here I share the plans that come out of the `PROFILE` statement:

**With node label**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dGmF_2zfKdGBtThm45MUUOkLSLCEHTYU/view?usp=sharing

**Without node label**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1efZWK6gXzNB0tjcKyhGIRFo22bDV8WjP/view?usp=sharing

I tried removing the `COLLECT` operation at the end but the query without `Product` label has still less db hits, 9325 against 13837. I'm afraid I am really new to Neo4j and I might be missing something super obvious here. What could possible cause db hit count to raise when a node label is added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is yes, when you have a label in your query, there will be db hits to filter on the label, so your eyes aren't deceiving you.

That said, not all db hits are equal. They are abstract units of db work, and label filtering is fairly lightweight.

There are times when you can leave a label off, and there are times where you really need to leave the label on.

If your model is such that only :Product nodes can be tagged like this, then you can leave out the label, as that's redundant. However, if there are other types of nodes that can be tagged, with :Product being only one of those, then you definitely need the :Product label in there for correctness.

The same applies for queries with longer paths, you may need to filter on node labels along the way, which should ensure you're minimizing the work needed for the rest of the expansions in the query, since you're only considering relevant paths with the correct labels in place.

Also, for some nodes in a pattern you may have properties on them, and having the label present allows the planner to consider using an index lookup, if an index is present on the label/property combination.

Comment: Pure gold. I can see now how the label will come in handy once queries grow in size.